# Why is this redirect not working? JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Why is this redirect not working in my managed bean?

```
HttpServletRequest objHttpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(objHttpServletRequest.getRequestURI() + "?abc=" + 1 + "&def=" + 2);
```

I think the problem is caused because of &. If i send just parameter(removing &), it works fine. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try replacing `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: Great! works fine :). Actually with h:commandButton it works just fine with & but i am using Primefaces, and with this components &amp; is must

Comment: @oedo: repost it as an answer then :) Actually, I didn't expect this solution to work and this is in fact not PrimeFaces specific but JSF implementation specific. @Nitesh: do you in the new request receive the **both** parameters?

Comment: @balusc, thanks! i wasn't sure it was going to work, but hey, i'm lucky today! :)

Comment: Hi Balusc, yep, i am receiving both the parameters. Primefaces is really non-standard, but since for my college i started using it for my project, i then didn't think of dumping it. I am thinking of moving to Richfaces but it doesn't support xhtml yet fully. Actually when i use & (with primefaces p:commandButton), the actionListener is fired but no redirect is done(not even any error in Server log)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `&` with `&amp;`.